# Are PIE *yóh₁r̥ "spring, summer" and Proto-Turkic *yāŕ "spring, summer" cognates?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, reconstruction

In Turkic it seems to be related to the word for "half" (yarım in modern Turkish).

The semantic development looks more likely into the direction half->spring rather than the opposite.

Comment: PIE *yóh₁r̥ does not mean 'spring'.

Comment: @Cairnarvon spring, summer, year. yāŕ means spring, summer, half a year.

Comment: Why do you say \*yóh₁r means "spring, summer"? Just because of the Slavic reflexes? Given that Germanic, Hellenic, Italic, Indo-Iranian, and probably others all show reflexes meaning "year" or "span of time" (and I believe all of those also have descendants of \*wésr for "spring"), it seems more plausible that the meaning "spring" arose later in Slavic.

Comment: @Draconis Okay, I agree, the meanining "spring" is possibly wrong here (in Russian spring is descendant of wesr). But the semantic development summer->year is much more probable than year->summer. In Slavic yóh₁r gave words for bright (яркий) and summer plants (Яровая культура). So, possibly the meaning was "summer" or "hot season".

Comment: Sure, _in Slavic_. But in many other branches, all its descendants mean "year/span of time", and there's a totally separate root for "spring" (wesr) and a separate root for "summer" (semh₂). It seems implausible that the word for "summer" shifted to mean "year" independently in every branch other than Slavic, and another root sprung up to mean "summer"; it seems much more plausible that Slavic lost that other root, and replaced it with the root for "year".

Comment: @Draconis as I said, semantic development summer->year is much more probable. Thus if it gave summer in Slavic, it should be summer already in PIE. The main word for a year in PIE was wetos. But words yóh₁r̥ and ǵʰéyōm "winter" also could be used when counting years.

Comment: @Draconis in Slavic the word "leto" (summer) shifted to mean year, "let" is now the main plural for "year".